# How to use git merge to revert master? (i.e. revert VIA merge)

Tags: git, merge

**Note:** There is no way this is the first time someone has asked this question. However, having searched for it, and only been able to find the answers to questions with similar words in the title but entirely different meanings, I have given up.

If you find the duplicate question, please close this and link to that question.

**Background:** Let's say you are working on master, and you have a lot of debug logging features. You want to share your code with someone else, but they hate your debug logs.

So, not wanting to distract them, you first make a new branch*, `debug_logging`, which contains the old (good) version of your code with all of the debug logs in it. Then you delete the debug logs from `master`.  Once the other person has seen your work and is satisfied with it, maybe helped you make some changes, you don't need to hide the debug logs from them and you can put the debug logs back into master. The problem is how to do this.

<sub>*Yes, the ideal would be to make the non-master branch the one with the logs deleted, but there are considerations external to this question which make that impossible.</sub>

> **Question:** If you want to restore the debug logs, you try to merge `debug_logging` onto `master`. But since `debug_logging` is technically behind `master` in history, `git checkout master; git merge debug_logging` does nothing (everything up-to-date).
>
> How can one merge `debug_logging` onto `master` in the sense of taking the union of the contents of their files (i.e. re-add the debug logs while keeping any additions made to `master` while the debug logs were gone)?
>
> This looks something like [merge-file](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-file) would do if it were possible to apply merge-file to all files in both branches in the repository simultaneously. Basically I want Git to stop acting smart, and merge `debug_logging` onto `master` the same way it would if they had no history in common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merging only makes sense when one branch is ahead of another. This means that you can only do a merge if you make commits on `debug_logging` that you then also want in `master`. You cannot use `git merge` to revert.

Instead you can use `git revert`. This command will create a new commit that effectively undoes the changes in one or more commits that you specify. The new commit will contain the reverse changes of the specified commits.

You will need a reference to the commits that you want to revert. The most direct way to refer to a commit is by its SHA hash. You can find the hashes for any commits with `git log`.

Comment: git revert won't work in this case because there were changes made to master which aren't in debug_logging

Comment: i guess I can just add an empty file and commit it to debug_logging and then delete it, but that seems like it's more work than it should be.

Comment: @roomwithaview 1. Your changes on master don't affect whether or not you can use `git revert`. I suggest you read the documentation, either by googling or runinng `git help revert`. 2. Creating an empty file on `debug_logging` and then merging into `master` will only add that empty file to `master`. It will not restore the debugging logging.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer because it sort of sounds like from the git man page that this is what I want, but I don't really understand the man page to be honest. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert . " revert the changes that the related patches introduce, and record some new commits that record them" -- what is meant by "related patches"? Related to what? "record them" -- record what?

Comment: @roomwithaview: The word *revert* is a bit problematic. Mercurial calls this operation `hg backout`. It means *Turn the commit I choose into a set of changes against its parent commit. Now, using those changes as instructions, make the **opposite** changes to the commit I have checked out, so as to back out the effect of that other commit.* So `git revert` equals `hg backout`: it backs out a previous commit.

Comment: @roomwithaview `git revert` applies a new commit. This commit contains reverses the changes from the commit you are reverting. The "related patches" refer to the textual changes of the commits you are reverting. "Related" here means "related to the commits". "Record them" means record the reverted changes.